# How to show different forms in react native on clicking different button in same screen

Tags: forms, react-native, popup

I tried googling my problem and it is only showing js files and code.i want to display one thing onpress of button but it is not showing up.i want it to be returned not making item invisible even if it is there.i want to popup in same screen like clicking on button a form and different form on clicking another.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,StatusBar,
  View,Button,Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
  }
 sayHello=() => {
    return(
      <View>
    {/* //<Text>hello</Text> */}
    Alert.alert('it is visible');
    </View>
    );
  }
render(){
  return (
    <View>
      {this.sayHello}
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.sayHello}><Text>hi </Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

I made this simple file as i am unable to resolve many errors..in the place of alert i would add a form.it is showing errors if i return more than one  component in the function.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to show another view by pressing a button! If that's what you want here is the code with functional Component!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Pressable } from 'react-native';
 const App = () => {
const [show, SetShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable onPress={() => SetShow(!show)}>
        {show === false ? <Text>Hi</Text> : <Text>Hello</Text>}
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};
```